# Entity Framework Many to Many columns concept

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many, conventions

I've been used to this kind of convention before starting to work with Entity Framework/MVC:

`tblMyItem (id, id_lookup1, val2, val3, val4...)` - single, generic table
`tblkLookup1 (id, val1, val2,...)` - one to many relation table
`tblmMyItemLookup2 (id, id_myitem, id_lookup2)` - many to many relations table.

Recently I've found somewhere on the web that it's not good to create `id` column in `tblmMyItemLookup2` when using Entity Framework, but I couldn't find more information on that. Could anyone please explain, why this is so significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing many-2-many relationship(i.e Student - Teacher) based on intermediate table (Student2Teacher) with only 2 foreign key columns, you'll end up having entities with navigation properties without intermediate table(no entity will be created for that table in context at all):

```
Student.Teachers <- EntityCollection<Teacher>
Teacher.Students <- EntityCollection<Student>
```

Meanwhile, if you add any extra field to your intermediate table, you'll have navigation properties pointing to intermediate entity:

```
Student.Student2Teacher
Teacher.Student2Teacher
```

making your querying uselessly more complex

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but adding additional columns besides those 2 foreign keys will create an unneeded table in the model instead of creating a collection of other class which makes it more easy to code?

Comment: right You are. One more entity in context. And navigation through many-2-many via intermediate entity: `Student.Student2Teacher.Teachers`

Answer (score 1):

In general we use lookup tables to macth associated records in two different tables that have a many to many relationship. For instance, let we have three tables: Students, Professors and StudentsProfessors. Since, a student can atten lesson that are serviced by many professors and a professor can teach more than one leasons then this is clearly a many to many relationship. So the lookup table called StudentsProfessors is used to match a student to her/his professors and vice versa. Now, the use of an id for each record of this lookup table is meaningless. We are not going to use this number anywhere. We just need to know that Student with studentId=10 is associated with professors with ids in (1,2,4,9). Just that and not the id of this record in the lookup table.

Comment: I just figured it out that the reason for using the id column was to make an index for the table, which is quite pointless..

Comment: Yeah exactly. Actually, I had faced some problems in a situation like yours, in which I was using EF 4. Then i deleted the id column and my problem was solved. A bit crazy, but that happened :)

Comment: composite key does the job